# RStudio ggplot2 two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to combine two plots into one. I find way how to do it, but now they are in two row. Like this:
[image: Plots in two rows]

I want them in one row. Thanks
Here is my code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")
library("gtable")
fig1 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=V2, y=V1))  +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + 
  geom_jitter(color = "darkblue", position=position_jitter(width=.05, height=0))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

fig2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=V1))  +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(fig1),
                ggplotGrob(fig2),
                size = "first"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your data ? See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: U can see my data in plots, its just numbers in one column.

Comment: No it's not only number as you are using `V1` and `V2` in your `geom_boxplot`. So what is V2 ?

Comment: V2="A" is string name. Its same for all numbers.

Comment: I just want to flip same plots in one row.

Comment: Do you want to have them side by side on a single row ? or fused together ?

Comment: I solved it. Just use this: plot_grid(fig1, fig2, labels = "AUTO").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two rows because you used rbind. For two columns, you can just cbind them:

```
fig1 = ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) + geom_point()
fig2 = ggplot(mtcars,aes(y=mpg,x=cyl,group=cyl)) + geom_boxplot()

grid.draw(cbind(ggplotGrob(fig1),ggplotGrob(fig2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `patchwork` package is an awesome way to do this:

```
library("ggplot2")
library(patchwork)

fig1 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=V2, y=V1))  +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + 
  geom_jitter(color = "darkblue", position=position_jitter(width=.05, height=0))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

fig2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=V1))  +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

fig1 + fig2
```

You can change the orientation easily and relative size very easily (although it will start with 2 in a row by default, so this isn't strictly needed.)

```
fig1 + fig2 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, width = c(1,2))
```